# CSS skewX and transform anchors

Tags: css

Hi I am in hurry and I need someone to help how to style my anchors like this. I styled it with transform: skewX(-10deg); but this second anchord should not have any 'transform' or 'rotation' on the right side. Like on this image.

here is the html markup

```
            <ul class="nav-elements">
                <li class="log"><a><span>Prijavi se</span></a></li>
                <li class="reg"><a><span>Registruj se</span></a></li>
            </ul>
```

And css style for span and li

```
                li.log, li.reg {
                    transform: skewX(-10deg);
                }

                span {
                  display: block;
                  transform: skewX(10deg);
                }
```

[image: Anchors]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how I solved this issue

Codepen link

http://codepen.io/husain100b/pen/PGpQQO

HTML code:

```
 <ul class="nav-elements">
    <li class="log"><a href="#"><span>Prijavi se</span></a></li>
    <li class="reg"><a href="#"><span>Registuj se</span></a></li>
 </ul>
```

CSS code:

```
 li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li {
    transform: skewX(-10deg);
    position: relative;
}

li.reg:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background: red;
      transform: skewX(10deg);
      left: 4px;
}
li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 9999;
  position: relative;
}
```